# TestCafe not finding testcafe module

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm evaluating TestCafe for use on our team and recently installed it on a Mac/OS running Monterrey 12.1 I realized the issue is that the node_modules were nowhere to be found. In typical Windows fashion, I just created a directory on the desktop and installed Testcafe. Apparently, the node modules were not installed or installed elsewhere. Is there a recommended process for installing Testcafe on a mac o/s? I'm running node v16.13.2, testcafe 1.18.3 . I don't typically use macs and had no issues with Testcafe on Windows. Maybe a newbie issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific recommendations for installing testcafe on macOs. Follow [instructions](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402834/guides/basic-guides/install-testcafe) - this should be sufficient.